# Query for number of questions asked per minute on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

How many questions are being asked on Stack Overflow per minute? I looked around and found this 6-year-old [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46747/how-many-questions-are-opened-daily-on-stackoverflow).

Instead of static values for current scenario, I was wondering if a Stack Overflow [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) can be constructed for knowing the current rate of question generation per minute.

Also, I have recently started following a few tags, including [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), and I feel that many more [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) questions are posted per minute, as compared to [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29). Can a tag specific query can be made to see if this is true?

Comment: You already have [a query for getting questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) that supports filtering by creation time and tag. That should be sufficient for getting the numbers you're after surely?

Comment: Ohh cool, I didn't know that. It's acceptable surely, but is it possible to make a query at (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46747/how-many-questions-are-opened-daily-on-stackoverflow) that gives answer in one number: rate of questions being asked currenly in tag X. It's just out of curiousity - nothing else though.

Comment: I was answering an identical question on MSE till it was deleted in the middle of me posting my answer. Given that the query can be adjusted by selecting the site so it runs against any site I don't see why it would need to be deleted there if it was cast as a questions per day on a site question. It's kind of annoying to work on an answer only to find that you can't submit it.

Comment: The thing about a well designed API isn't that it solves every question you could think of but that it gives you the *tools* to solve every question you can think of. There's no need for the API to return that number because it gives you the tools to find it. Imagine the nightmare of maintaining that codebase if they were to make a new query endpoint every time someone wanted to figure out some metric about the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/490701/questions-per-minute) for it.

```
select count(*) / 1440.0
from postswithdeleted p
where datepart(year, getdate()) = datepart(year, p.creationdate)
and datepart(dayofyear, getdate()) - 7 = datepart(dayofyear, p.creationdate)
and p.posttypeid = 1 -- questions
```

It returns the average number of questions asked 7 days ago (because SEDE can be a few days old).

It uses postswithdeleted thanks to gnat so that it gets all questions.

Comment: 10 days a go means that query results will probably miss quite a bunch of questions [automatically deleted by 9-days roomba script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773). If I understand correctly missing data is stored in a dedicated table called [PostsWithDeleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/165773)

Comment: @gnat I've updated it to be 7 days ago which is a much simpler change.

Comment: since your query uses only creationdate and posttypeid there is a chance that simply chnging from to use postswithdeleted instead of posts would work

Comment: @gnat updated per your advice, it does increase the average a little.